# PyQt QAbstractTableModel emit dataChanged seems to causes too many calls for data in QTableView?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a QTableView linked to a QAbstractTableModel. When data is changed I emit a dataChanged event using indexes to the top left and bottom right values as well as a constraint on the types updated. If I use index values for a single cell data is refreshed for just that cell (but all roles). If I change the second index to be anything other than the same cell all cells seem to be refreshed. This seems to not be as I expected so I am probably missing something?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, model):

        super().__init__()
        self.setModel(model)


class Model(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        self.source_data = [[0, 0, 0], [10, 10, 10]]

    @pyqtSlot()
    def tick(self):

        self.source_data[0][0] += 1
        self.source_data[0][1] += 1
        self.source_data[0][2] += 10
        self.source_data[1][2] += 10

        # Test 1 - this asks for a single cell and seems to work - (but for all roles?)
        #index_1 = self.index(0, 0)
        #index_2 = self.index(0, 0)
        #self.dataChanged.emit(index_1, index_2, [Qt.DisplayRole])

        # Test 2 - this always seems to ask for all data to be refreshed not just the two cells I said (again all roles)
        index_1 = self.index(0, 0)
        index_2 = self.index(0, 1)
        self.dataChanged.emit(index_1, index_2, [Qt.DisplayRole])

    def rowCount(self, parent_index=None):
        return 2

    def columnCount(self, parent_index=None):
        return 3

    @pyqtSlot()
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()

        print("Called for (%s, %s, %s)" % (row, col, role))

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.source_data[row][col]

        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):

        return None


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    m = Model()
    w = Window(m)
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is using Qt version: 5.6.1 and PyQt version: 5.5.1

Comment: AFAICS, the docs for [dataChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) don't specify how the model/view will behave after the signal has been emitted.